# Are there legal consequences for having my salary leaked internally on a document?

Tags: united-states, legal, payroll

My payroll allocation/information was leaked and shared internally. Naturally, I am furious over this and undoubtedly there will be fallout. I am seeking your input as to whether or not there are any legal consequences my company is facing for leaking this confidential information.

Comment: You should add location to your question

Comment: We can't answer legal questions, but even if you re-word it, you'll need to put in a location.

Comment: And yes, as @thursdaysgeek mentions, you may be bettet contacting a lawyer. Just think if it is worth to fight for disclosure of such information. Does it really affect you?

Comment: wow - I didn't expect to get responses so quickly. This website is awesome.

Comment: Yes, SE is a great place :) still, your question seems to be off topic, as you are requesting legal guidance (check what questions are [on topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site).

Comment: for me, it's an invasion of privacy. new employee (management) and now already difficult counterparts who are jealous of me being hired are only going to be that much more difficult, which in turn is going to directly affect my success as a manager and a leader now. Moreover, the person who leaked it will likely not suffer any repercussions only damaging my credibility even further. so, yes, it does feel like it's affecting me.

Comment: I guess my question is too far off topic for this website apparently even though I found plenty of questions I would consider in the same realm. In either context. Don't need legal advice.

Comment: You might re-word the question for what are steps to take as a manager and leader, now that the payroll information has been leaked, so that you can still be successful.

Answer (score 4):

- Do you have a provision in your contract that prohibits **Your Employer** from disclosing your salary?
- Are their laws in your area that would prohibit **your employer** from disclosing your salary?
- Has the leaking of your salary caused actual damages?

If the answer to all 3 of those are no, then your answer is probably no.

If the answer to even one of these yes then you should take all the documentation you have relating to this incident to a lawyer and get their opinion.